# How do I copy a WordPress menu without a plugin?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

For many reasons it isn't always ideal to install a plugin on multiple sites  just to copy content. For pages / posts it's really easy to grab the post content and copy+paste (even when using page builders the content is available in an underlying textarea). Menus on the other hand are a pain. What is your goto method for copying menus?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I whipped up today to solve copying WordPress menus via JavaScript / without a plugin.

First navigate to the menu you want to copy and paste this into the console.

```
var items = jQuery('#menu-to-edit li');
var json = [];

jQuery.each(items, function(i, item) {
    item = jQuery(item);
    var title = item.find('.edit-menu-item-title').val();
    var url = item.find('.edit-menu-item-url').val();
    var classes = item.find('.edit-menu-item-classes').val();
    var description = item.find('.edit-menu-item-description').val();

    var menuitem = {"title" : title, "url" : url, "classes" : classes, "description" : description};
    json.push(menuitem);
});
JSON.stringify(json);
```

Copy that output and navigate to the new menu - paste the content into the parse statement below:

```
var json = JSON.parse('PASTED DATA HERE');

function addItem(item)
{
    jQuery('#custom-menu-item-url').val(item.url);
    if (item.url == "")
    {
        item.url = "#";
    }
    jQuery('#custom-menu-item-name').val(item.title);
    jQuery('#submit-customlinkdiv').click();
}
```

Then simply shift elements out of that json element and into the addItem function.

```
addItem(json.shift());
```

Rinse and repeat until your items are added.

There is lots of room for optimization on this e.g. it could add the classes / descriptions, re-order the menu items in the correct depth, add extended properties or monitor the add menu item form and automatically add the next item for you - could become a handy bookmarklet to beat back throwaway plugins like those that do simple menu copies.